# I am not able to understand how generics are used in this code in nodejs module http.d.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, extends, typeof

```
  type RequestListener<
        Request extends **typeof IncomingMessage = typeof IncomingMessage**,
        Response extends **typeof ServerResponse = typeof ServerResponse**,
    > = (req: InstanceType<Request>, res: InstanceType<Response> & { req: InstanceType<Request> }) => void;
```

what is the meaning of the bold part here

I thought of trying hit and try method to see what it means. But I don't know how and what to check here. I think that request extends the IncomingMessage type, but don't know how is that possible.

Comment: Where did you find that code? I ask because the `RequestListener` type in Node.js's `http` module is not like that, it's just `type RequestListener = (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => void;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class like `IncomingMessage`, `typeof IncomingMessage` is the type of the *constructor function* of that class (whereas `IncomingMessage` is the type of *instances* of the class). So that code is saying that `Request` is a constructor function that extends the `IncomingMessage` constructor function. (And the same sort of thing for `Response`.)

The `= ____` part says what the default for the type parameter is if none is provided explicitly. So if you did `listener: RequestListener;`, the type parameters would take their default values (`typeof IncomingMessage` and `typeof ServerResponse`), but if you did `listener: RequestListener<X, Y>`, the type parameters would take the values `X` and `Y` instead.